# Search and click any textual button in Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, productivity

I am looking for a program that can search for and activate any visible button with a text for the frontmost application.

It should work on Microsoft Windows. Gratis is preferable.

On Mac OS X 10.10 I use  [Shortcat](https://shortcatapp.com/):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[SikuliX](http://www.sikulix.com/) is an excellent GUI testing tool that uses OpenCV to scan the screen for which components to select before moving on to the next action. As such it can locate buttons that move between versions, etc.

- Free Gatis & Open Source
- Windows XP->10 & OS-X & Linux
- Scripting Support in Python, Ruby, Java
- Can search for text on the screen using OCR.

Using the IDE to locate this text on screen ***And type this instead*** and click post
Before I ran it the line above ended with here in with * either side which was found as an image on the screen!

[image]

Comment: Not as polished as Shortcat but indeed the closest program I am aware of in Microsoft Windows.

Comment: And the only one with a reasonable chance of writing cross platform scripts